# Event fired twice if call a form

Tags: vb.net

***Can anyone help avoid this ?***

At an event handler, I need cal a form but after the form is unloaded the event is fired again.

```
    Private Sub MyHandler(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txObjName.Leave

        Dim MyVar As Integer = SomeValue

        dim myForm as SomeForm
        MyForm.ShowDialog()
```

***After myForm be closed, the event is fired again***

Comment: Is this all code in `Sub MyHandler`? Im asking because, everything after `MyForm.ShowDialog()` won't be executed until `MyForm` is being closed.

Comment: No, there is more code, this is just a sample. After the form is called ( and closed ) all the code is executed again...

Comment: Do you set the handler somewhere else with `AddHandler`?

Comment: Do you use SetFocus on textbox anywhere? Please show more code

Comment: No MatSnow, there's no any AddHandler

Comment: @GCoe Please show more code like fofik wrote. (and use @ before alias, i've seen your comment only by chance)

Comment: I'll do it @MatSnow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing :

```
Handles txObjName.Leave
```

by

```
Handles txObjName.LostFocus
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought is to try make use of the `FormClosing` event.

So your code will look like this:

```
Private _Closing as boolean = False
Private Sub MyHandler(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txObjName.Leave
    If Not _Closing Then
        Dim MyVar As Integer = SomeValue
        Dim myForm as SomeForm
        MyForm.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    _Closing = True
End Sub
```

And you make use of the `FormClosing` event to toggle the boolean `_Closing` to true, so the code will not execute when the form is closed :)

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution and only works if `Sub MyHandler` is in the same class as `SomeForm`. It is not clear from the question whether this is the case.

Comment: Hi Jaxi, the event is fired after MyForm is closed and not the main form...

Comment: Instead of MyBase.FormClosing you could use `AddHandler` instead maybe?